# Programmatically create button on WPF canvas

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas

How would I programmatically create button on canvas by using canvas coordinates from some source (ie. database)

I have canvas which I need to populate with buttons, I will be using for each loop to create buttons with coordinates that are in database.

```
 <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="308" Margin="10,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="815">
        <Button Name="Button2" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="130" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button2_Click" />
        <Button Name="Button3" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="23" Canvas.Left="618" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button2_Click" />
    </Canvas>
```

I can create button programmatically but I can't seem to set all WPF/Canvas properties through VB.NET code

```
  Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

Dim n As New Button
    n.Width = 20
    n.Height = 20
    n.Content = "TV"
    canvas1.Children.Add(n)
   End Sub
```

How would I set: Canvas.Top, Canvas.ZIndex, Canvas.Left?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found the solution.

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim n As New Button
    n.Width = 200
    n.Height = 200

    ' Set Canvas position 
    Canvas.SetLeft(n, 10)
    Canvas.SetTop(n, 10)
    ' Add Button to Canvas 
    canvas1.Children.Add(n)
End Sub
```